# Java create Scroll List

Tags: java, swing, list, scroll

I am trying to make a scrollable List which should have 2 columns (Label and TextFields) and the amount of the rows 
depends on the input.

```
private void inflateList() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(10, 45, 343, 166);

    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(names.size(), 2 , 5 , 5));
    for (String str:names){
        panel.add(new JLabel(str));
        JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        months.add(tf);
        panel.add(tf);
    }
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(scroll , BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: What do you get when you run it? An exception or a broken looking layout? Any chance of a stack trace or a screenshot?

Comment: It doesn't add anything to the frame

Comment: Why do you add your TextField to months? What is months?

Comment: Are you adding the scroll pane at runtime? In that case the layout needs to be revalidated. Also, consider `JTable` or `JList`, they may be more appropriate than inventing your own.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post a [Minimal Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.